# Rolling window function (uniqueN) in R by date range

Tags: r, data.table, rolling-computation

I have a data set where I want to perform rolling functions over a date range.

I have currently done this via a loop, where I subset the main data for each range, then do the calculations and piece it together. It works well but the actual data set is over 2M rows and it took over 15 minutes to complete.

```
library(data.table)
start_date <- as.Date(fast_strptime("2021-03-04", "%Y-%m-%d"))
end_date <- start_date + 2
output <- data.table(NULL)
d = structure(list(date = structure(c(18690, 18690, 18692, 18692, 18692, 18693, 18693, 18694, 18695, 18695, 18695), class = "Date"),
                   id = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 2, 1),
                   w = c(3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1)),
              row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

while (end_date < Sys.Date()) {
  
  
  x <- d[date >= start_date & date <= end_date, .(tw = sum(w)), 
         by = .(id)]
  
  
  
  setorder(x, -tw, id)
  x[, wprop := {x = sum(tw); y = cumsum(tw) / x}]
  x[, idprop := {x = uniqueN(id); y = 1:.N / x}]
  
  start_date <- end_date + 1
  end_date <- start_date + 2
  
  x[, start_date := start_date]
  x[, end_date := end_date]

  output <- rbindlist(list(output, x))
  
    
}
```

I would prefer a data.table solution since I will be doing this for a few different time windows so I need it to be as fast as possible.

Comment: Though the question has been answered, yet can you please elaborate what you're trying to do here?

Comment: In real life, I am aggregating data over a 60 day period and working out performance relative to other competitors, similar to pareto. So within each window I need to know the unique number of active competitors and their stats. I modifield the answer below slightly because I update this daily, so the stats are from from today are from day -1 to day minus 60 and so on going backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, iteratively building (*growing*) a frame (or `data.table`) can be a problem, so my first thought would be to wrap this in `lapply` instead of a `while` loop. This would generate a list of `data.table`s, after which we would do a single `rbindlist`. This alone should provide a significant speed improvement in your 2M datasets.

```r
start_dates <- seq(as.Date(fast_strptime("2021-03-04", "%Y-%m-%d")), 
                   max(d$date) + 1, by = "3 days")
list_of_tables <- lapply(start_dates, function(start_date) {
  x <- d[date >= start_date & date <= start_date + 2L, .(tw = sum(w)), by = .(id)]
  setorder(x, -tw, id)
  x[, wprop := {x = sum(tw); y = cumsum(tw) / x}]
  x[, idprop := {x = uniqueN(id); y = 1:.N / x}]
  x[, start_date := start_date + 3L]
  x[, end_date := start_date + 5L]
  x
})
rbindlist(list_of_tables)
#       id    tw     wprop idprop start_date   end_date
#    <num> <num>     <num>  <num>     <Date>     <Date>
# 1:     1     5 0.5000000   0.50 2021-03-07 2021-03-12
# 2:     2     5 1.0000000   1.00 2021-03-07 2021-03-12
# 3:     4     5 0.3846154   0.25 2021-03-10 2021-03-15
# 4:     2     4 0.6923077   0.50 2021-03-10 2021-03-15
# 5:     1     2 0.8461538   0.75 2021-03-10 2021-03-15
# 6:     3     2 1.0000000   1.00 2021-03-10 2021-03-15
```

---

Another method would be to use `data.table`'s range-joins, doing it a little more directly.

```r
ranges <- data.table(start_date = seq(as.Date(fast_strptime("2021-03-04", "%Y-%m-%d")),
                                      max(d$date)+1, by="3 days"))
ranges[, end_date := start_date + 2L]
ranges
#    start_date   end_date
#        <Date>     <Date>
# 1: 2021-03-04 2021-03-06
# 2: 2021-03-07 2021-03-09
# 3: 2021-03-10 2021-03-12
```

From here,

```r
tmp <- d[ranges, on = .(date >= start_date, date <= end_date)
  ][, .(tw = sum(w)), by = .(date, id)
  ][!is.na(id),]
setorder(tmp, -tw, id)
tmp[, c("wprop", "idprop") := .(cumsum(tw)/sum(tw), seq_len(.N)/uniqueN(id)), by = .(date)
  ][, c("start_date", "end_date") := .(date + 3L, date + 5L)
  ][, date := NULL]
#       id    tw     wprop idprop start_date   end_date
#    <num> <num>     <num>  <num>     <Date>     <Date>
# 1:     1     5 0.5000000   0.50 2021-03-07 2021-03-09
# 2:     2     5 1.0000000   1.00 2021-03-07 2021-03-09
# 3:     4     5 0.3846154   0.25 2021-03-10 2021-03-12
# 4:     2     4 0.6923077   0.50 2021-03-10 2021-03-12
# 5:     1     2 0.8461538   0.75 2021-03-10 2021-03-12
# 6:     3     2 1.0000000   1.00 2021-03-10 2021-03-12
```

Notes:

- Because the LHS of the join is `ranges`, there might be ranges with zero data, resulting in `NA` in the other fields. This is a natural side-effect of the join and this sample data; I don't know if it'll be an issue, but the `[!is.na(id),]` is meant to do that. I think an inner-join would feel more natural, but `data.table::[`-join semantics only support left joins.
- I combined the assignment (of `wprop` and `idprop`) into a single `[`-line, no real reason, it can be separate calcs.
- The range join is destructive to the column names of join keys for the table on the LHS of the join (which is the inner frame, `ranges`), so what we would like to reference as `start_date`/`end_date` are then known as `date`/`date.1` immediately post-join. Fortunately we lose no data and don't strictly need `date.1` this time, so it's a graceful recovery. (I could have renamed `date` to `start_date` instead of a new assignment, it might be more efficient for 2M rows, so feel free to see if it helps you.)

FYI: with *this* data, benchmarking suggests that the range-join method runs in less than half the time compared to the list-of-frames method above. I doubt that that ratio will remain when the data size increases significantly. **Please come back** after trying both methods with your 2M row data and report run-times. Thanks!

Comment: please come back with a runtime comparison, I'm really curious how the two methods scale.

Comment: the lapply method was 2.15 seconds and the other method took 4.5 seconds, which is an incredible speed bump on the way I originally did it.